# Codeigniter: Dropdown passing null value to database whenever try to edit a profile

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I'm posting this second time i'm stuck here for almost a week. I have a website and i need to change profile info through admin panel. Now the issue is whenever i click on edit button and do changes on profile such has change name or email changes are accepted but when i try to changes the address such as change country through dropdown and then i changes city accourding to the selected country and submit those changes i gives me nothing means in database no changes are made and instead of changes i get nothing in county,province column in database they become blank no data I hope you got my point!! let me show you the code

edit_profileoverseasadmin.php

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("form").submit(function(){
            var e = document.getElementById("select");
            var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
            document.getElementById("hidden20").value = strUser;

            var e1 = document.getElementById("selectcity");
            var strUser1 = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].text;
            document.getElementById("hidden31").value = strUser1;

            var e2 = document.getElementById("selectcontinent");
            var strUser2 = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].text;
            document.getElementById("hidden32").value = strUser2;

            var e3 = document.getElementById("selectprovince");
            var strUser3 = e3.options[e3.selectedIndex].text;
            document.getElementById("hiddenprovince").value = strUser3;

        });
    });
</script>

<script>
    function OverseasValidation() {
        $("#loaderIcon").show();
        var e = document.getElementById("select");
        var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("hidden20").value = strUser;


        var e1 = document.getElementById("selectcity");
        var strUser1 = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("hidden31").value = strUser1;

        var e2 = document.getElementById("selectcontinent");
        var strUser2 = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("hidden32").value = strUser2;

        var e3 = document.getElementById("selectprovince");
        var strUser3 = e3.options[e3.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById("hiddenprovince").value = strUser3;

        var rate_value;
        if (document.getElementById('male').checked) {
            rate_value = document.getElementById('male').value;
        }
        else{
            rate_value = document.getElementById('female').value;
        }
        document.getElementById("hidden25").value = rate_value;
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>check_validation.php",
            data:'hidden1='+$("#hidden1").val()+'&hidden2='+$("#hidden2").val()+'&hidden3='+$("#hidden3").val()+'&hidden4='+$("#hidden4").val()+'&hidden5='+$("#hidden5").val()+'&hidden6='+$("#hidden6").val()+'&hidden15='+$("#hidden15").val()+'&hiddencardholder='+$("#hiddencardholder").val()+'&hiddenaddress='+$("#hiddenaddress").val()+'&hiddenzip='+$("#hiddenzip").val()+'&hiddencardno='+$("#hiddencardno").val()+'&hiddencardexpiry='+$("#hiddencardexpiry").val()+'&cardcvv='+$("#cardcvv").val(),
            type: "POST",
            success:function(data){
                if(data == "Success")
                    {
                        var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
                        x.setAttribute("type", "submit");
                        x.setAttribute("value","Register");
                        $("#user-availability-status10").html(x);
                        //document.getElementById("hidden1").value = data;
                        $("#loaderIcon").hide();
                    }
                else if(data == "<span class='status-not-available'>Enter correct Card CVV format.</span>"){
                     $("#user-availability-status11").html(data);
                     $("#loaderIcon").hide();
                }
                else{
                     $("#user-availability-status11").html(data);
                     ("#loaderIcon").hide();
                }
            },
            error:function (){}
        });
    }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $("#loaderIcon").show();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>name.php",
            data:'phone='+$("#phone").val(),
            type: "POST",
            success:function(data){
                $("#countrydropdown").html(data);
                $("#loaderIcon").hide();

                var e1 = document.getElementById("select");
                e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].text = document.getElementById("hdcountry").value;

                var e2 = document.getElementById("selectcontinent");
                e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].text = document.getElementById("hdcontinent").value;
            },
            error:function (){}
        });

        var city = "13";
        var country = "AF";
        $("#loaderIcon").show();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>editcity.php",
            type: "POST",
            success:function(data){
                $("#citydropdown").html(data);
                $("#loaderIcon").hide();

                var e1 = document.getElementById("selectcity");
                e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].text = document.getElementById("hdcity").value;
            },
            error:function (){}
        });
   });

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var country_code = "AF";
        $("#loaderIcon").show();
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo base_url();?>province_state.php",
            data: { country_code : country_code},
            type: "POST",
            success:function(data){
                //  alert(data);
                $("#provincedropdown").html(data);
                $("#loaderIcon").hide();

                var e1 = document.getElementById("selectprovince");
                e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].text = document.getElementById("hdprovince").value;
            },
            error:function (){}
       });

       $("#loaderIcon").show();
           jQuery.ajax({
               url: "<?php echo base_url();?>district.php",
               //data:'phone='+$("#phone").val(),
               type: "POST",
               success:function(data){
                   $("#districtdropdown").html(data);
                   $("#loaderIcon").hide();
               },
               error:function (){}
          });
          $("#loaderIcon").show();
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>tehsil.php",
        //data:'phone='+$("#phone").val(),
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
        $("#tehsildropdown").html(data);
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();

    },
    error:function (){}
    });
    $("#loaderIcon").show();
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>uc.php",
        //data:'phone='+$("#phone").val(),
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
        $("#ucdropdown").html(data);
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();

    },
    error:function (){}
    });
    });

</script>








function checkstate() {
    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>check_state.php",
    //data:'cnic='+$("#cnic").val(),
    data:'state='+$("#state").val(),
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
        $("#user-availability-status111").html(data);
        document.getElementById("hiddenstate").value = data;
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();

    },
    error:function (){}
    });
}

function checkAddress() {
    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>check_address.php",
    //data:'cnic='+$("#cnic").val(),
    data:'address='+$("#address").val(),
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
        $("#address-availability").html(data);
        document.getElementById("hiddenaddress").value = data;
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();

    },
    error:function (){}
    });
}
function checkCity() {
    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>check_city.php",
    //data:'cnic='+$("#cnic").val(),
    data:'city='+$("#city").val(),
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
        $("#city-availability").html(data);
        document.getElementById("hiddencity").value = data;
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();

    },
    error:function (){}
    });
}

function checkCardcvv() {
    var e = document.getElementById("select");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("hidden20").value = strUser;


    var e1 = document.getElementById("selectcity");
    var strUser1 = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("hidden31").value = strUser1;

    var e2 = document.getElementById("selectcontinent");
    var strUser2 = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("hidden32").value = strUser2;

    var e3 = document.getElementById("selectprovince");
    var strUser3 = e3.options[e3.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("hiddenprovince").value = strUser3;


    var rate_value;
    if (document.getElementById('male').checked) {
    rate_value = document.getElementById('male').value;
    }
    else{
        rate_value = document.getElementById('female').value;
    }
    document.getElementById("hidden25").value = rate_value;
    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>check_cardcvv.php",
    //data:'cnic='+$("#cnic").val(),
    data:'cardcvv='+$("#cardcvv").val(),
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
        $("#cardcvv-availability").html(data);
        document.getElementById("hiddencardcvv").value = data;
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();

    },
    error:function (){}
    });
}
function checkSilsala() {
    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>check_silsala.php",
    //data:'cnic='+$("#cnic").val(),
    data:'silsala='+$("#silsala").val(),
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
        $("#user-availability-status7").html(data);
        document.getElementById("hidden7").value = data;
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();

    },
    error:function (){}
    });
}
function checkBlock() {
    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>check_block.php",
    //data:'cnic='+$("#cnic").val(),
    data:'block='+$("#block").val(),
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
        $("#user-availability-status8").html(data);
        document.getElementById("hidden8").value = data;
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();

    },
    error:function (){}
    });
}
function checkProvince() {
    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>check_province.php",
    //data:'cnic='+$("#cnic").val(),
    data:'state='+$("#state").val(),
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
        $("#user-availability-status9").html(data);
        document.getElementById("hidden9").value = data;
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();

    },
    error:function (){}
    });
}
function checkContinent() {
    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo base_url();?>check_continent.php",
    //data:'cnic='+$("#cnic").val(),
    data:'continent='+$("#continent").val(),
    type: "POST",
    success:function(data){
        $("#user-availability-status39").html(data);
        document.getElementById("hidden39").value = data;
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();

    },
    error:function (){}
    });
}
</script>
<body>
<script>
function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#blah')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)
                        .width(120)
                        .height(150);
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }


</script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  

    $(".my-activity").click(function(event) {
        var total = 120;
        /*var lensector=$(this).find('input[name="check_list[]"]:checked').length;
        document.getElementById("hidden29").value = lensector;

        var lenoffice=$(this).find('input[name="check_list1[]"]:checked').length;
        document.getElementById("hidden30").value = lenoffice;*/
        var countsectors = 0;
        var countoffice = 0;
        var countwings = parseInt(document.getElementById("wings").value);
        //alert(checkedBoxes);
        $(".my-activity:checked").each(function() {
                if($(this).val() == "UC Member"){
                    countoffice += 1;
                    total += 5000;
                }
                else if($(this).val() == "Tehsil President"){
                    countoffice += 1;
                    total += 10000;
                }
                else if($(this).val() == "District President"){
                    countoffice += 1;
                    total += 25000;
                }
                else if($(this).val() == "Commerce & Trade"){
                    countwings += 1;
                    //total += 10000;
                }
                /*else if($(this).val() == "Commerce"){
                    countwings += 1;
                    //total += 10000;
                }*/
                else if($(this).val() == "Industry"){
                    countwings += 1;
                    //total += 10000;
                }
                else if($(this).val() == "Lawyer"){
                    countwings += 1;
                    //total += 25000;
                }
                else if($(this).val() == "Doctor"){
                    countwings += 1;
                    //total += 10000;
                }
                else if($(this).val() == "Minorities"){
                    countwings += 1;
                    //total += 25000;
                }
                else if($(this).val() == "Women_Development"){
                    countwings += 1;
                    //total += 10000;
                }
                else if($(this).val() == "Functionary"){
                    countwings += 1;
                    //total += 25000;
                }
                else if($(this).val() == "Other"){
                    countwings += 1;
                    var data = '<input type="text" id="otherfield" name="otherfield">';
                    $("#otherfield").html(data);
                    //total += 25000;
                }
                else{
                    countsectors += 1;
                    total += 120;
                }

        });



        if (total == 120) {
            $('#amount').val('120');
        } else {                
            $('#amount').val(total);
        }
        document.getElementById("hidden29").value = countsectors;   

        document.getElementById("hidden30").value = countoffice;
        document.getElementById("wings").value = countwings;
        var amount = total;
        document.getElementById("payment").value = total;
    });

}); 
</script>
<script>
window.onload=function() {

  document.getElementById("countrydropdown").onchange=function() {
    //var period = this.value;
    var e = document.getElementById("select");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("hidden20").value = strUser;

    //var e = document.getElementById("select");
    var ctry = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("hiddencountry").value = ctry;
        jQuery.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>province_state.php",
        data: { country_code : strUser},
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
        $("#provincedropdown").html(data);
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();

    },
    error:function (){}
    });
  }

     document.getElementById("provincedropdown").onchange=function() {
    var e = document.getElementById("selectprovince");
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById("hidden20").value = strUser;

    var ctry = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("hiddenstate").value = ctry;

    var rate_value;
    if (document.getElementById('male').checked) {
    rate_value = document.getElementById('male').value;
    }
    else{
        rate_value = document.getElementById('female').value;
    }
    document.getElementById("hidden25").value = rate_value;

    var e1 = document.getElementById("select");
    var strUser1 = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].value;

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>city.php",
        data: { country : strUser1 , city : strUser },
        type: "POST",
        success:function(data){
        $("#citydropdown").html(data);
        //document.getElementById("hiddencity").value = strUser;
        $("#loaderIcon").hide();

    },
    error:function (){}
    });
  }
}
</script>
<?php $this->load->view('header'); ?>
<!--Form Start-->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9">


 <h2><legend class="alignright"><u>Edit Profile</u></legend></h2>

<div class="col-lg-5">
<h3>Membership #    <strong><?php echo $membershipno;?></strong></h3>
<h4><?php echo $province; ?></h4>
</div>

<?php echo form_open_multipart("admin/editprofileoverseas/".$id);?>

<div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-1">
<?php if($pic_path != './profile_pics/'):?>
<img id="blah" src="<?php echo base_url().$pic_path;?>" height="150"/>
<?php else: ?>
<img id="blah" src="https://nabobil.no/assets/default_profile_pic-05d39cb795bbb98e10c104b8f4aba70677a3f9f6c13253bf94f16181e9ee5a99.gif" height="150"/>
<?php endif; ?>
<input type='file' name="myFile" onchange="readURL(this)"; />
</div>

<br>
<br>
   <span class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="color:#D91E18"> <?php echo $message;?></span>


   <div class="controls col-md-5">
      <label class="control-label"  for="username">Full Name</label> *<br>
       <!--<input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" onBlur="checkAvailability2()">-->
       <?php echo "<input name='firstname' type='text' class='form-control' id='firstname' value='$first_name' />";?><span id="user-availability-status2"></span>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" id="hidden2" name="hidden2" value="">



      <div class="controls col-lg-5">
      <label class="control-label"  for="relation">Father / Husband Name</label><br>
       <?php echo "<input name='relation' type='text' class='form-control' id='relation' value='$relation' />";?>
      </div>
       <div class="controls col-lg-5">
      <label class="control-label"  for="username">Date Of Birth</label><br>
       <?php echo "<input name='dob' type='text' class='form-control' id='dob' value='$birth_date' />";?><span id="user-availability-status15"></span>
      </div>
    <!--<div class="control col-md-5">
    <label class="control-label" for="email">CNIC</label><br>

      <?php echo "<input name='cnic' type='text' class='form-control' id='cnic' value='$cnic' />";?><span id="user-availability-status3"></span>
    </div> 
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden3" name="hidden3" value="">-->







      <input type="hidden" id="hidden4" name="hidden4" value="">



      <input type="hidden" id="hidden15" name="hidden15" value="">



      <!--<div class="controls col-md-5">
      <label class="control-label" for="email">E-mail</label> *
      <br>

    <?php echo "<input name='email' type='text' class='form-control' id='email' value='$email' />";?><span id="user-availability-status1"></span>
      </div>

      <input type="hidden" id="hidden1" name="hidden1" value="">




    <input type="hidden" id="hidden5" name="hidden5" value="">

     <div class="control col-md-5">
    <label class="control-label" for="email">Gender</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" id="male" checked="true"> Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" id="female"> Female<br>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" id="hidden25" name="hidden25" value="">-->

   <!-- <div class="control col-md-5">
    <label class="control-label" for="email">Profile Picture</label><br>
    <input type='file' name="myFile" onchange="readURL(this)"; />
    </div>-->

    <div class="control col-md-5">
    <label class="control-label" for="email">Landline Number</label><br>
    <?php echo "<input name='phone' type='text' class='form-control' id='phone' value='$phone' />";?>
    </div>

    <div class="control col-md-5">
    <label class="control-label" for="email">Mobile Number</label> *<br>
    <!--<input type="tel" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="03012345678" onBlur="checkMobile()">-->
     <?php echo "<input name='mobile' type='text' class='form-control' id='mobile' value='$mobile' />";?><span id="user-availability-status6"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden6" name="hidden6" value="">

    <div class="control col-md-5">
    <label class="control-label" for="email">Email Address</label> *<br>
    <!--<input type="tel" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="03012345678" onBlur="checkMobile()">-->
     <?php echo "<input name='email' type='text' class='form-control' id='email' value='$email' />";?><span id="user-availability-status1"></span>
    </div>
<div class="control col-md-5">
    <label class="control-label" for="email">Mailing Address</label> *<br>
        <?php echo "<textarea name='mailingaddress' rows='10' cols='160' class='form-control' id='mailingaddress'>$mailingaddress</textarea>";?>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="control col-md-5">
     <label class="control-label" for="email"></label><br>
    <span id="countrydropdown"></span>
    </div>-->



    <div class="row Weddings">




  </div>

  <!--<div class="control col-md-5">
      <label class="control-label"  for="username">Continent</label><br>
       <input type="text" id="continent" name="continent" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" onBlur="checkContinent()"><span id="user-availability-status39"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden39" name="hidden39" value="">-->
  <div class="control col-md-5">

    <label class="control-label" for="email">Country</label> *<br>
    <span id="countrydropdown"></span>
    <?php
    $selected='';
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","","","freedomorg");
      $sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,name FROM countries");
        if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)){
        $select= '<select name="select" id="select">';
while($rs=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
{
      if($rs['name']===$country)
      {
        $select.='<option selected="selected" value="'.$rs['id'].'">'.$rs['name'].'</option>';
      }
      else
      {
      $select.='<option value="'.$rs['id'].'">'.$rs['name'].'</option>';
      }

  }
  $select.='</select>';
echo $select;
}
//P}OaK[oW@s[U

?>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden20" name="hidden20" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="hiddencountry" name="hiddencountry" value="">
    <div class="control col-md-5">

    <label class="control-label" for="email">Continent</label> *<br>
    <select id="selectcontinent">
      <option value="Asia">Asia</option>
      <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
      <option value="North America">North America</option>
      <option value="South America">South America</option>
      <option value="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
      <option value="Europe">Europe</option>
      <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
    </select>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" id="hidden32" name="hidden32" value="">


        <div class="control col-md-5">
      <label class="control-label"  for="username">State/Province *</label><br>
       <span id="provincedropdown"></span>
         <?php
//       $country_code = $_POST["country_code"];
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","","","freedomorg");
    $sql1=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT code FROM countries WHERE name='$country'");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql1);
    $result=$row['code'];
 $sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT code,name FROM regions WHERE country='$result' order by name ASC");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)){
$select= '<select name="select" id="selectprovince">';

while($rs=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
    if($rs['name']===$province)
    {
      $select.='<option selected="selected" value="'.$rs['code'].'">'.$rs['name'].'</option>';
  }
  else
  {
    $select.='<option value="'.$rs['code'].'">'.$rs['name'].'</option>';    
  }
  }
  $select.='</select>';
echo $select;
}


?>
     <!--  <input type="text" id="state" name="state" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" onBlur="checkstate()"><span id="user-availability-status111"></span><!--onBlur="OverseasValidation()"><span id="user-availability-status11"></span>-->
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenprovince" name="hiddenprovince" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenstate" name="hiddenstate" value="">
     <?php echo "<input name='hdprovince' type='hidden' id='hdprovince' value='$province' />";?>
    <?php echo "<input name='hdcountry' type='hidden' id='hdcountry' value='$country' />";?>
    <?php echo "<input name='hdcity' type='hidden' id='hdcity' value='$city' />";?>
    <?php echo "<input name='hdcontinent' type='hidden' id='hdcontinent' value='$continent' />";?>
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden21" name="hidden21" value="">
    <div class="control col-md-5">
      <label class="control-label"  for="username">City *</label><br>
      <span id="citydropdown"></span>
      <?php
      $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","","","freedomorg");
      $sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,name FROM cities WHERE name != '' order by name ASC");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)){
$select= '<select name="select" id="selectcity">';
while($rs=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
        if($rs['name']===$city)
        {
            $select.='<option selected="selected" value="'.$rs['id'].'">'.$rs['name'].'</option>';
        }
        else
        {
            $select.='<option value="'.$rs['id'].'">'.$rs['name'].'</option>';  
        }
  }
  $select.='</select>';
echo $select;
}
?>
       <!--<input type="text" id="city" name="city" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" onBlur="OverseasValidation()"><span id="user-availability-status11"></span>-->
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" id="hiddencity" name="hiddencity" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden31" name="hidden31" value="">

















    <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-9 col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-8">

<?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');?> <?php echo form_close();?>
  </div>
  </div>


  <br>
<br>


  </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Tehsil Council wali bakwas-->

<br>
<br>

<!--Form End-->

<!-- Footer Start -->

<?php $this->load->view('footer'); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just surprised a line of code `$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","","","freedomorg");`, and you mentioned that you are using codeigniter LOL

Comment: @Bira Lol sir what if i tell you i'm using codeigniter!! i didn't developed the site but im managing it!! so theirs alot of code which i don't know about!! but the exact same code is working on my localhost but not on server

Comment: You can avoid queries from view section,and give database information in database.php file - @Dawood

Comment: @ubm sir will this resolve the issue? because the code is working prefectly on my localhost but its not working properly on server sir

Comment: @Dawood: This is not regarding your issue, when you write codes like that in to a framework, it will be very difficult for maintenance, just think about the next guy who will join your company and maintain this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try mvc structure,i hope this code will helps you to find your issue correctly
You should add db details in to `database.php` file

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'database' => 'db_name',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

And this is my controller file

```
    <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {


    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('sitemodel');

    }
    public function index()
    {
        $data['countries'] = $this->sitemodel->get_country();
        $this->load->view('welcome_message',$data);
    }
}
```

Then `Sitemodel.php`

```
    <?php

    if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
        exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Sitemodel extends CI_Model {

        function __construct() {
            // Call the Model constructor
            parent::__construct();
        }

        function get_country() {
            $this->db->select('id,name');
            $this->db->from('countries');
            $data = $this->db->get()->result();
            return $data;
        }
}
```

And finally i just added view file with drop down

```
 <select name="country" id="country">
<?php
foreach($countries as $country)
{
?>
<option value="<?= $country->id?>">"<?= $country->name?></option>
<?php
}
?>
        </select>
```

i hope this will helps you

Comment: sir let me try and change my code according to your suggestion

Comment: sir can tell you something about my code? may be i can point put the where the issue is?

Comment: Please add only the specific portion of code which cause problems - @Dawood

Comment: sir i don't know exactly but i guess this portion is causing the probelm but if you look at onchange function in my code i guess that's where is problem is

Comment: which is you'r form submission function

Comment: hello sir sorry for late reply!! i went out of city! your code sir did helped me thankyou sir thanks alot!! but now i need more help sir. the code you gave me its working fine now i need to show province with this code! means if i selected america in country dropdown then province of america should display in the province dropdown from database!! can you help me here sir?

Comment: what did you get for `var_dump($_POST);` in controller

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment but it could be so many reason.

People in comment are talking about the mysqli_connect because your information are surely wrong.
You have to put user and password as second and third argument in the mysqli_connect function, depending of your production server id/password.
You don't have any error code ?

Also but out of question, Code igniter have a build in database.. Look here : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/news_section.html (depending of your CI version)

Comment: i removed the username and password just to post my code here i have my username and passwird in my code and i don't have any error!! the code works fine on locahost!! but when it comes to server its not working perfectly!! i can edit name email but when it comes to select country and province from drop down thats where the problem its not editing  country and province instead its return blank column in database

Comment: Make sure mysqli extension is installed in your server

Comment: @Dawood are you **sure** that the database schema in server is the same as in local ?

Comment: @Bira seem like other DB operation work, I don't think this could change something

Comment: `CodeIgniter/application/config/database.php` inside this file can you tell me the value for `dbdriver` ?

Comment: @Bira value is mysql

Comment: Then use `mysql_connect`, but for much better solution use the first answer by ubm